# Current request is not a multipart request in Angular but works in Postman

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

I have a working upload backend with Postman. But I can't make it work from angular.

**Backend code**:

```
package com.demo.web.api.file;

import static java.nio.file.Files.copy;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/files")
public class FileUploadService {

    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {

        Log.info("Processing file upload...");

        List<String> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

        // Upload directory
        final String DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Documents/Uploads";

        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            try {
                Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY, fileName).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
                copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptions.add(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            fileNames.add(fileName);
        }

        if (!exceptions.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(exceptions);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(fileNames);

    }

}
```

Here's a sample execution in Postman that returns the list of uploaded files:
[image]

As seen in the image above, the backend code is working as expected.

**upload.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from 'src/shared/services/app-config.service';
import getClassNameForExtension from 'font-awesome-filetypes';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss'],
})
export class UploadComponent {
  files = [];
  totalSize: number = 0;
  maxUploadSize: number;
  fileExtensions: Array<string> = [];
  hasInvalidFile: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private appConfigService: AppConfigService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.maxUploadSize = this.appConfigService.configData.maxUploadSize;
    if (this.appConfigService.configData.fileExtensions) {
      const extensions =
        this.appConfigService.configData.fileExtensions.split(',');
      extensions.forEach((ext) => {
        this.fileExtensions.push(ext.trim());
      });
    }
  }

  onFileDropped($event) {
    this.prepareFilesList($event);
  }

  fileBrowseHandler(files) {
    this.prepareFilesList(files);
  }

  deleteFile(index: number) {
    let newSize = 0;
    this.files.splice(index, 1);

    let allValid = true;
    this.files.forEach((file) => {
      if (file.invalidFileExtension) {
        allValid = false;
      }
      newSize += file.size;
    });

    this.hasInvalidFile = !allValid;
    this.totalSize = newSize;
  }

  uploadFilesSimulator(index: number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (index === this.files.length) {
        return;
      } else {
        const progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
          if (this.files[index]) {
            if (this.files[index].progress === 100) {
              clearInterval(progressInterval);
              this.uploadFilesSimulator(index + 1);
            } else {
              this.files[index].progress += 5;
            }
          }
        }, 200);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  prepareFilesList(files: Array<any>) {
    for (const file of files) {
      // const ext = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
      file.progress = 0;

      const extension = file.name.split('.').pop();
      file.extension = extension;

      const className = getClassNameForExtension(extension);
      file.className = className;

      if (
        this.fileExtensions.length > 0 &&
        !this.fileExtensions.includes(extension)
      ) {
        file.invalidFileExtension = true;
        this.hasInvalidFile = true;
      }

      this.files.push(file);
      this.totalSize += file.size;
    }
    this.uploadFilesSimulator(0);
  }

  /**
   * Format size in bytes
   * @param bytes (File size in bytes)
   * @param decimals (Decimals point)
   */
  formatBytes(bytes) {
    if (bytes === 0) {
      return '0 Bytes';
    }
    const k = 1024;
    const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(2)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }

  upload() {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (const file of this.files) {
      formData.append('files', file);
    }

    this.spinner.show();
    this.http.post(`http://localhost:16080/files/upload`, formData);
  }
}
```

**upload.component.html**

```
<div class="ui-g" style="height: 87vh">
  <!-- Spinner -->
  <ngx-spinner
    bdColor="rgba(189,188,188,0.6)"
    size="medium"
    color="#4a4848"
    type="ball-beat"
    [fullScreen]="true"
  >
  </ngx-spinner>
  <div
    class="ui-lg-12 ui-md-12 ui-g-12"
    style="padding: 1.25%; padding-bottom: 0; height: 99%"
  >
    <mat-card
      class="ui-lg-12 ui-md-12 ui-g-12 app-card"
      style="height: 100%; overflow: auto"
    >
      <!-- Card-header -->
      <div class="app-card-header flex-align-center ui-lg-12 ui-md-12 ui-g-12">
        <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
        <div class="ui-lg-12 ui-md-12 ui-g-12 p-0 d-flex align-center">
          <i
            [matTooltip]="''"
            matTooltipClass="mat-tool-cust"
            class="fas fa-table-cells-large app-icon-head ocular-app-card-header-icon"
          ></i>
          <span style="padding: 0 8px"> Data Processing </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Card Content -->
      <div class="upload-container" (fileDropped)="onFileDropped($event)">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input
            type="file"
            #fileDropRef
            id="fileDropRef"
            multiple
            (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)"
          />
          <i class="fas fa-regular fa-upload"></i>
          <h3>Drag and drop files here</h3>
          <h3>or</h3>
          <label
            for="fileDropRef"
            class="app-btn1 mat-raised-button mat-button-base"
            >Click here to browse files</label
          >
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="files-list">
        <div class="single-file" *ngFor="let file of files; let i = index">
          <div class="file-icon">
            <i class="fa {{ file.className }}" style="font-size: 20px"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <h4
              class="name"
              [ngClass]="file.invalidFileExtension ? 'strike-through' : ''"
            >
              {{ file?.name }}
            </h4>
            <p class="size">
              {{ formatBytes(file?.size) }}
            </p>
            <app-progress [progress]="file?.progress"></app-progress>
          </div>

          <div class="delete-ctn" (click)="deleteFile(i)">
            <i class="fas fa-trash action-icons" matTooltip="Delete"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="upload-btn-container"
        *ngIf="
          files.length > 0 && (hasInvalidFile || totalSize > maxUploadSize)
        "
      >
        <div style="justify-content: center; color: red">
          Files cannot be uploaded. Some files may not be in the supported
          format ({{ fileExtensions }}) or the total allowable upload size may
          have exceeded {{ formatBytes(maxUploadSize) }}.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="upload-btn-container"
        *ngIf="
          files.length > 0 && !hasInvalidFile && totalSize <= maxUploadSize
        "
      >
        <button
          type="submit"
          (click)="upload()"
          mat-raised-button
          class="app-btn2 save-btn"
        >
          Upload Files
        </button>
      </div>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Payload
[image]

Error I'm getting

```
nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

I can see a slight difference in the payload from Postman as it gives the full path. But that is not possible to achieve in javascript for security purpose.
[image]

Comment: What is the value of the content-type header that is send when making the request using Angulars http-client? Is there any chance that your body contains formdata but the content-type header is set incorrectly so Spring starts to complain?

Comment: @Palladium02 I wasn't setting it. I just tried Arif Khan's answer and I'm now getting a different error. I'm researching about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original code is working as expected. The problem is in our project, there's an **HttpInterceptor**. that automatically appends a header of `'Content-Type', 'application/json'` if it wasn't passed.

I added this in my http call.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('isUpload', 'true');
this.http.post(`http://localhost:16080/files/upload`, formData, {headers});
```

And in the interceptor, I added a condition to preserve the previous logic.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpParams,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MessageComponent } from '../message/message.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RequestInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  etagValue = undefined;

  // error dialog ref var
  dialogRef!: MatDialogRef<MessageComponent>;

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: request.headers.set('calling-entity', 'UI'),
    });

    if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      if (!request.headers.has('isUpload')) {
         request = request.clone({
           headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
         });
      }
    }

    if (
      request.params instanceof CustomHttpParams &&
      request.params.etagValue
    ) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'If-Match': request.params.etagValue,
        },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe();
  }
}

export class CustomHttpParams extends HttpParams {
  constructor(public etagValue: any) {
    super();
  }
}
```

After commenting out the part where Content-Type was being set, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the header Content-Type: file, It should resolve the issue.

```
this.http.post(`http://localhost:16080/files/upload`, formData, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'file'
      }
);
```

Or

```
const _headers = new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'file'
});

this.http.post(`http://localhost:16080/files/upload`, formData, 
      headers: _headers
);
```

Comment: I just tried this and the error changed. I'm now getting this: ```[org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException Invalid mime type "file": does not contain '/']```

Comment: Could you please try to change file to multipart/form-data , like this 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: I actually just tried and I got the following error: ```; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found] with root cause
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found```

Comment: may be need to change some code in spring boot like below, please try this also......@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public boolean addDocument(@RequestPart("properties") Document document, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {

Comment: try 'Content-Type': undefined

Comment: I've tried your suggestions above. Nothing have worked yet. This looked promising: ```const _headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${Math.random().toString(36)}`});``` But the backend isn't getting the passed file.

Comment: Thanks, @Arif Khan. Your suggestions led me to the correct solution to my problem. I've just posted it. It was a problem within our codebase where we defined an interceptor that automatically sets the Content-Type to application/json.

Comment: Thanks for updating @ericute, comment headers in the interceptor will cause issues with other APIs, instead, you can create one more if the condition and reset the header there for your API.